# Using is_in_stock as layered navigation

Tags: product-attribute, layered-navigation, stock-status

I need is_in_stock to be exposed as an attribute for which I can set "Use in layered navigation" to "Filterable (with results".

I can't seem to find a way to do this? I can't find an extension which does this? Does anyone have any ideas?

To clarify: I'm using ElasticSearch as my search backend, and ElasticSearch takes over layered navigation by using it's own facets which mirror the attribute settings for Layered Navigation - so that's why I need a stock attribute.

Comment: Bad (but easy) idea: create attribute, sync it with the stock status.

Comment: Thanks - Would you mind elaborating? Creating a attribute is easy enough but how would I go about 'syncing with the stock status' ?

Comment: You have to register a observer on every event which might change the stock status and update your attribute. And be careful this can be a performance killer.

Comment: Thanks to Fabian Blechschmidt, I got an idea.

I'm checking stock levels on my import script and assigning an 'in stock' or 'out of stock' value to an attribute which I apply to all products

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own questions :-)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt you could also put an answer here :P

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new attribute, name it e.g. `is_in_stock` and sync it with the stock status.

Depending on the way you import products, you need to hook into:

- importing products
- saving products (in backend)
- buying products
- returning products/canceling orders/...

Then you can just use the attribute.

Not sure whether this is a good idea, especially because it might cost a lot of performance.

**The (better?) alternative is to implement your own layer model and block to do what you want.**